# Sharing ui-router 'custom data' between sibling states

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, angular-ui-router

I thought this was possible, but I may be wrong. From a child state, can I share 'custom data' of a parent state between two sibling states?

*Update: Yes it is possible, there must just be something wrong with my own code. Here is a [simplified example on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fy61hGJILvYYu84urokK). For historical reasons, the rest of my question continues below. Note that my original code example had a typo that had `chidl2` instead of `child2`, which is why @originof used it in his answer.*

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do.

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
        data: {
            sharedArray: []
        }
    })
    .state('parent.child1', {
        url: '/child1',
        controller: 'Child1Ctrl',
        templateUrl: 'js/lib/parent/child1.tpl.html',
    })
    .state('parent.child2', {
        url: '/child2/:id',
        controller: 'Child2Ctrl',
        templateUrl: 'js/lib/records/parentitem.tpl.html'
    });
});
app.controller('Child1Ctrl', function ($state) {
    // This is always loaded first
    $state.current.data.sharedArray.push("child 1 adding data data");
});
app.controller('Child2Ctrl', function ($state) {
    // This is always loaded from a Child1Ctrl
    console.log($state.current.data.sharedArray); // Says '[]'
})
```

Basically, I want to:

1. set up an array in a parent, abstract state (`parent`);
2. transition to a child state (`parent.child1`) and update the array;
3. transition to a second child state (`parent.child2`) and still have access to the update array.

Currently, I am able to view and change the array inside `parent.child1`, but then when I immediately transition to `parent.child2`, the custom data, `$state.current.data.sharedArray`, is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to modify parent.child12 to parent.child1.child12.

if your flow is parent -> child1 -> child12 the real angular flow is parent -> child1, parent -> child12, so in child12 the sharedArray is always []

Comment: Something must be wrong with my setup. Even as a child of the child -- and nested views so I can see the original view --  I still see an empty `sharedArray`. Before the transition, it is fully populated and after the transition it is empty. I will see if I can work out something on plunkr.

Comment: Yeah. There must be a problem with my implementation.  Here is a [working plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/fy61hGJILvYYu84urokK)

Answer (score 1):

I am leaving this question as answered by @originof, but I tracked down the real source of my problems and it has nothing to do with UI-Router, at least not directly.

If you are trying to share an array between sibling states, you have to be very careful to only mutate the array if you expect it to survive -- it will overwrite the parent (prototype) array with a local array if you use an assignment (that is, don't write `$state.current.data.sharedArray = [1, 2, 3]`).

Doing this (mutating an array) can be a bit challenging depending on what you are doing because functions like `push()` and `splice()` can't be used to merge arrays very easily (you basically have to serialize your array in the function call), while functions like `concat()` requires reassignment (because it returns a new array).

Here is what I am likely going to do:

```
// First, empty the shared array
$state.current.data.sharedArray.splice(0, $state.current.data.sharedArray.length); 

// Next, merge the new array
Array.prototype.push.apply($state.current.data.sharedArray, newArrayData);
```

This is very fast and direct, but it is pretty inelegant and inscrutable, so it requires some documentation if you expect to know what is going on here. Yes, it might be simpler to iterate over your new array and add the elements one-by-one, but if your array is very large, this will end up being almost certainly much, much slower.